# python 関数の値の保持範囲（スコープ）について

Tags: python, python3

関数の勉強を行っております。
関数で保持される値のスコープについて質問があります。

下記2つの関数がありますが、1つ目の関数内の completed_designs.append(current_print)　で
空のリストに値を格納しておりますが、この格納した値は、ほかの関数（ここでは、def show_completed_models(completed_modeles):）でも値は保持され続けているということで
良いのでしょうか？

```
def print_models(unprinted_designs, completed_designs):
    """
    リストから無くなるまで印刷する。
    印刷後、cpmpleted_designsに移動する。
    """
    while unprinted_designs:
        current_print = unprinted_designs.pop()
        print(f"印刷中->{current_print}")
        completed_designs.append(current_print) # 質問箇所

def show_completed_models(completed_modeles):
    """
    印刷されたものを表示する。
    """
    
    for completed_model in completed_modeles:
        print(f"印刷完了->{completed_model}")
        

unprinted_designs = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
completed_designs = []

print_models(unprinted_designs, completed_designs)
show_completed_models(completed_designs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

はい。値は保持され続けています。
変数completed_designsは下から4行目のところ、関数の外で定義されていますから、グローバルなスコープで変数が定義されていることになります。

その定義された変数を関数の引数で渡している(下から2行目,1行目)ので、
関数print_modelsでも関数show_completed_modelsでも同じリストを参照していることになります。

Answer (score 0):

下から2行目で`print_models(unprinted_designs, completed_designs)`と呼び出した際に、

- `print_models`関数のローカル変数としての`unprinted_designs` = 呼び出し元の`unprinted_designs`、
- `print_models`関数のローカル変数としての`completed_designs` = 呼び出し元の`completed_designs`、

と名前付けが行われます。よって、`print_models`関数内で`unprinted_designs`や`completed_designs`に対して変更操作を行うと、呼び出し元の`unprinted_designs`や`completed_designs`への操作が行われます。

`print_models`関数が終了すると、関数スコープでのローカル変数としての名前付けは解消されますが、呼び出し元での`unprinted_designs`や`completed_designs`に行った操作が取り消されるわけではありません。